# Use COUNT.IF and INDIRECT together

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use a function that uses COUNT.IF and INDIRECT at the same time.

```
=COUNT.IF('Sheet1'!$D$3:INDIRECT("MA" & E4);1)
```

seems to work but

```
=COUNT.IF('Sheet1'!INDIRECT("D" & E5):INDIRECT("MA" & E6);1)
```

doesn't. 
Does anyone know how to solve this ? 
Thanks !

Comment: For your consideration only: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/indirect-excels-most-evil-function/

Comment: Try this formula. `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!D" & E5&"MA" & E6),1)` . You can indirect a range inside indirect, but you cannot use 2 indirect to form range.

Comment: Excel doesn't accept that formula either ! It gives #REF error.

Comment: Actually you can use two indirects to form a range =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"D" & E5):INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"MA" & E6),1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!D" & E5 & ":MA" & E6),1)
```